# Tkinter, why is my window formatted like this?

Tags: python, tkinter, format

This is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("Calculator")
root.geometry("100x200")

text = Text(root, height = 1, width = 10)

text.grid(row = 0, column = 0)


b1 = Button(root, text="1", command= lambda: text.insert(END, str(1)))
b1.grid(row = 1, column = 0)


b2 = Button(root, text="2", command= lambda: text.insert(END, str(2)))
b2.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

b3 = Button(root, text="3", command= lambda: text.insert(END, str(3)))
b3.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

b4 = Button(root, text="4", command= lambda: text.insert(END, str(4)))
b4.grid(row = 1, column = 3)
```

When I execute the code, my formatting is all messed up:

[image]

Does it have to do with the way I use .grid()?

Comment: Why do you consider it messed up? What do you expect it to be that's different from what it is?

Comment: I guess you probably want to use `columnspan=4` inside `text.grid(...)`?

Comment: window displays correctly with your code - grid is like table in excel - in first column you create entry and button `1` and it displays it in first column, in second column you create button `2` and it displays it in second column, etc. What did you expect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your window is formatted like that because unless configured further `grid` makes the widget to have around as least amount of pixels as possible for a given content, and that it also assumes every node in a grid occupies the same amount of space (maximum least required among all nodes, in the example entry widget has the largest pixel requirement) for that row or column.

An entry widget as far as I know *defaults* to *20* characters wide width and 1 character tall height.

And the button widget requires exactly the amount of space required by what's inside, `"1"`, `"2"`, `"3"` etc. in your case.

And since 20 character is wider than 1 character there's an empty space around 1 character button in order to match that of entry widget's width.

There can be some ways of preventing that, one that I can think of is:

changing `text.grid(row = 0, column = 0)` to `text.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan=4)` so that it spans not only 1 column but 4 so that it matches the entirety of the buttons under it.

Comment: _"An entry widget as far as I know requires 12 character wide width and 1 character tall height."_ - that is incorrect. You can create an entry widget any size you want, though anything smaller than 1 character high or one character wide would be fairly useless.

Comment: I meant that as in it defaults to that.

Comment: If you meant "defaults" instead of "requires", you should write it that way. These types of technicalities matter when talking about technical subjects to beginners.  Also, the default is 20, not 12.

Answer (score 1):

It displaying like that because your geometry size is small to display all the widget in your window and also grid works like arrangement in excel sheet so you can increase or decrease the row size or column size to position it where you want it.look at the button named `2` i increase the row and column sizes

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.title("Calculator")
root.geometry("200x200")

text = Text(root, height = 1, width = 10)

text.grid(row = 0, column = 0)


b1 = Button(root, text="1", command= lambda: text.insert(END, str(1)))
b1.grid(row = 1, column = 0)


b2 = Button(root, text="2", command= lambda: text.insert(END, str(2)))
b2.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

b3 = Button(root, text="3", command= lambda: text.insert(END, str(3)))
b3.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

b4 = Button(root, text="4", command= lambda: text.insert(END, str(4)))
b4.grid(row = 1, column = 3)
```